# Subtract the values of multiple dictionaries with the same keys

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a database (python's tinydb) with dictionaries. Each of these dictionaries contains data for a specific epoch time:

Dictionary 1 = {'epochtime' = 1480417585, 'apple' = 1.25, 'melon' = 2.50}

Dictionary 2 = {'epochtime' = 1480422580, 'apple' = 1.40, 'melon' = 2.30}

Dictionary 3 = ...

I want to compare the change of value for each fruit for each epoch time:

- What is the change of prices for each fruit, between Dictionary 1 and 2?
- What is the change of prices for each fruit, between Dictionary 2 and 3?
- ...

Obviously I need to subtract the values in chronological order (high epoch time - low epoch time, low epoch time - even lower epoch time, etc.).

I'm certain there are python gurus who can write that in a couple of lines, but I'm completely stumped at the moment!

I'm using Python 3, but Python 2.7 advice will be more than helpful too.

Comment: Sort the dictionaries based on the value of `epochtime`; then subtract each value from the next one. Come back if you need help with a specific step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first step is to sort your entries by epoch time. Assuming they're in a list `entries`,

```
sorted_entries = sorted(entries, key=lambda e: e['epochtime'])
```

The `key` parameter is a function which maps each entry to a value that specifies the sort order for the collection. Hence `sorted_entries` will now contain all of your entries by ascending epoch timestamp.

To actually get the results, you can just iterate through in pairs:

```
for i in range(len(sorted_entries)-1):
    first, second = sorted_entries[i], sorted_entries[i+1]

    # Do whatever calcs you need
    print("Apple change: {}".format(second['apple'] - first['apple']))
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked with a tiny bit of modifying of my own code!